# Would the following code make an http request to the server?

Tags: c#, .net, httprequest

Would this code make a http request or is it just faking it?

```
var writer = TextWriter.Null;
var response = new HttpResponse(writer);
var request = new HttpRequest("DummyFile.aspx", HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString(),
                              "__EVENTTARGET=true&__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED=true");
var context = new HttpContext(request, response);

var page = new Page
               {
                   EnableViewStateMac = true,
                   ViewStateEncryptionMode = ViewStateEncryptionMode.Always
               };
page.ProcessRequest(context);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is faking the presence of a HttpRequest. Nothing goes across the wire when executing this code.